# How do I get a title for the window in lightweight charts using python?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have the following python code that gives me the following window:

```
import pandas as pd
from lightweight_charts import Chart

SYMBOL = 'GOOGL'

def get_bar_data(symbol, timeframe):
    if symbol not in ('AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'TSLA'):
        print(f'No data for "{symbol}"')
        return pd.DataFrame()
    return pd.read_csv(f'parttime_larry/lightweight-chart/bar_data/{symbol}_{timeframe}.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chart = Chart(toolbox=True)
    chart.legend(True)   

    chart.topbar.textbox('symbol', SYMBOL)   
    df = get_bar_data(SYMBOL, '5min')
    chart.set(df)   

    chart.show(block=True)
```

[image]

But unfortunately the chart doesn't have a title, which I absolutely need for pyautogui. Is there an easy way to give the lightweight chart a title (as in the following image WINDOWS 1 inserted using Photoshop)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. install the latest version 1.0.18.6 and paste the following:

chart = Chart(title='MyTitle', toolbox=True)